# Creation of a "temporary" table for daily operations?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, redbean

I have a mysql table MAINLIST.

```
CREATE TABLE `MAINLIST` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `NAME` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `contact` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Every day I select a subset of these and perform some operations. Right now I do this within the  MAINLIST table, but I think it would be helpful for organization, readability and debugging to create a second table daily import the selected records, do the operations and then send the records back to the Mainlist table and destroy the daily table.

What is the best way to do this with mysql, or are there other ways to approach this problem? Perhaps I should not be doing this at all. I am wondering what best practices are since I'm not experienced with Db design. I am using the redbean ORM and php.

Comment: even with 5 million records your query time would be minimal on a table that 'thin' - how many transactions are you doing a day?

Comment: Less than a thousand transactions. maybe 100-200 records need to have daily transactions. the actual table has about 10 fields (I've simplified it for the question) . Again, this is not for performance purposes, but more for separation of concerns, ie I can have a separate controller for the daily table. Also its easier to monitor whats going on . Mainlist has maybe 9000 records total. - Thanks, Bill